# ECS Cluster problem: no container instance met all of its requirements

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs

**Roles:**

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "ecs-ec2-role" {
  name = "${var.app_name}-ecs-ec2-role"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": [
          "ecs.amazonaws.com",
          "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
        ]
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_instance_profile" "ecs-ec2-role" {
  name = "${var.app_name}-ecs-ec2-role"
  role = "${aws_iam_role.ecs-ec2-role.name}"
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "ecs-ec2-role-policy" {
  name = "${var.app_name}-ecs-ec2-role-policy"
  role = "${aws_iam_role.ecs-ec2-role.id}"

  policy = <<EOF
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
              "ecs:CreateCluster",
              "ecs:DeregisterContainerInstance",
              "ecs:DiscoverPollEndpoint",
              "ecs:Poll",
              "ecs:RegisterContainerInstance",
              "ecs:StartTelemetrySession",
              "ecs:Submit*",
              "ecs:StartTask",
              "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
              "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
              "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
              "ecr:BatchGetImage",
              "logs:CreateLogStream",
              "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents",
                "logs:DescribeLogStreams"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
EOF
}

# ecs service role
resource "aws_iam_role" "ecs-service-role" {
  name = "${var.app_name}-ecs-service-role"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": [
          "ecs.amazonaws.com"
        ]
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "ecs-service-attach" {
  role = "${aws_iam_role.ecs-service-role.name}"
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonEC2ContainerServiceRole"
}


data "aws_iam_policy_document" "aws_secrets_policy" {
  version = "2012-10-17"
  statement {
    sid = ""
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = ["secretsmanager:GetSecretValue"]

    resources = [
      var.aws_secrets
    ]
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "aws_secrets_policy" {
  name   = "aws_secrets_policy"
  policy = "${data.aws_iam_policy_document.aws_secrets_policy.json}"
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "aws_secrets_policy" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.ecs-ec2-role.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.aws_secrets_policy.arn
}
```

**ECS:**

```
resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "main" {
  name = "${var.app_name}-cluster"
}

data "template_file" "app" {
  template = file("./templates/ecs/app.json.tpl")
  vars = {
    app_name          = var.app_name
    app_image         = var.app_image
    app_host          = var.app_host
    endpoint_protocol = var.endpoint_protocol
    app_port          = var.app_port
    container_cpu     = var.container_cpu
    container_memory  = var.container_memory
    aws_region        = var.aws_region
    aws_secrets       = var.aws_secrets
  }
}

resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "app" {
  family                   = "${var.app_name}-task"
  execution_role_arn       = aws_iam_role.ecs-ec2-role.arn
  cpu                      = var.container_cpu
  memory                   = var.container_memory
  container_definitions    = data.template_file.app.rendered
}

resource "aws_ecs_service" "main" {
  name            = "${var.app_name}-service"
  cluster         = aws_ecs_cluster.main.id
  task_definition = aws_ecs_task_definition.app.arn
  desired_count   = var.app_count
  iam_role = aws_iam_role.ecs-service-role.arn
  depends_on = [aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.ecs-service-attach]

  load_balancer {
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.app.id
    container_name   = var.app_name
    container_port   = var.app_port
  }
}
```

**Autoscaling:**

```
data "aws_ami" "latest_ecs" {
  most_recent = true

  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["*amazon-ecs-optimized"]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "virtualization-type"
    values = ["hvm"]
  }

  owners = ["591542846629"] # AWS
}

resource "aws_launch_configuration" "ecs-launch-configuration" {
  // name = "${var.app_name}-launch-configuration"
  image_id = data.aws_ami.latest_ecs.id
  instance_type = var.instance_type
  iam_instance_profile = aws_iam_instance_profile.ecs-ec2-role.id
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.ecs_tasks.id]

  root_block_device {
    volume_type = "standard"
    volume_size = 100
    delete_on_termination = true
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }

  associate_public_ip_address = "false"
  key_name = "backend-dev"

  #
  # register the cluster name with ecs-agent which will in turn coord
  # with the AWS api about the cluster
  #
  user_data = data.template_file.autoscaling_user_data.rendered
}

data "template_file" "autoscaling_user_data" {
  template = file("./templates/ecs/autoscaling_user_data.tpl")
  vars = {
    ecs_cluster = aws_ecs_cluster.main.name
  }
}

#
# need an ASG so we can easily add more ecs host nodes as necessary
#
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "ecs-autoscaling-group" {
  name = "${var.app_name}-autoscaling-group"
  max_size = "4"
  min_size = "2"
  health_check_grace_period = 300
  desired_capacity = "2"
  vpc_zone_identifier = [aws_subnet.private[0].id, aws_subnet.private[1].id]
  launch_configuration = aws_launch_configuration.ecs-launch-configuration.name
  health_check_type = "ELB"
  tag {
    key = "Name"
    value = var.app_name
    propagate_at_launch = true
  }
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_policy" "demo-cluster" {
  name                      = "${var.app_name}-ecs-autoscaling-polycy"
  policy_type               = "TargetTrackingScaling"
  estimated_instance_warmup = "90"
  adjustment_type           = "ChangeInCapacity"
  autoscaling_group_name    = aws_autoscaling_group.ecs-autoscaling-group.name

  target_tracking_configuration {
    predefined_metric_specification {
      predefined_metric_type = "ASGAverageCPUUtilization"
    }

    target_value = 40.0
  }
}
```

Cluster name was added to an Instances successfully via User Data:

```
$ cat /etc/ecs/ecs.config 
ECS_CLUSTER=mercure-cluster
```

But I'm getting an error:

> service mercure-service was unable to place a task because no
>   container instance met all of its requirements. Reason: No Container
>   Instances were found in your cluster.

**ecs-agent.log:**

```
$ grep 'WARN\|ERROR' ecs-agent.log.2019-10-24-10
2019-10-24T10:36:45Z [WARN] Error getting valid credentials (AKID ): NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.
2019-10-24T10:36:45Z [ERROR] Unable to register as a container instance with ECS: NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.
2019-10-24T10:36:45Z [ERROR] Error registering: NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.
```

**ecs-init.log:**

```
$ grep 'WARN\|ERROR' ecs-init.log 
2019-10-24T10:36:45Z [WARN] ECS Agent failed to start, retrying in 547.77941ms
2019-10-24T10:36:46Z [WARN] ECS Agent failed to start, retrying in 1.082153551s
2019-10-24T10:36:50Z [WARN] ECS Agent failed to start, retrying in 2.066145821s
2019-10-24T10:36:55Z [WARN] ECS Agent failed to start, retrying in 4.235010051s
```

Comment: Are there container instances registered in the cluster? What does `aws ecs list-container-instances --cluster mercure-cluster` show?

Comment: Also it looks like your EC2 instances IAM policy are missing a few required actions. You can either use the [`AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/instance_IAM_role.html) directly or implement all the required actions if you need to diverge from this.

Comment: No, that's the issue - no instances added to a cluster in spite they were started by Terraform. Regarding `AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role` - I was using 
[ECS-Cluster](https://github.com/markdavidburke/ECS-Cluster/blob/master/iam.tf) repo for reference and there is no such role used, take a look please.
BTW, if you run this `ECS-Cluster`, everything works fine.

Comment: Have you checked the cloud init logs? Or checked the logs for the ECS agent?

Comment: I can see something - "Availability Zone contains no healthy targets". I think this is because no tasks were started within an Instances thus nothing is listening on port 3000 (should be Mercure container).

Comment: I have added logs entries

Comment: I have fixed it by adding `ec2.amazonaws.com` to Instance Role. I don't understand why `ECS-Cluster` example is working then... Strange

Comment: Oh, I missed that entirely. You weren't allowing the EC2 instance to assume the role at all because it didn't have the correct trust relationship and was only allowing the ECS service and ECS tasks to assume it.